# Same p-value. Is it normal?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, kruskal-wallis-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I did the following comparisons with a Wilcoxon test on MatLab, and I got the same p-value on both. Is this normal? Is there something wrong?

Also, the tests indicate not to reject H0. How to interpret this if the values seem to be different. The values are raw runtimes in seconds from different programming languages on the same algorithm.

Comparison 1:

```
>>language1= [122.784323072
    123.245732096
    122.825708288
    123.730597120
    123.664524800] 
>>language2= [66.954494208
    71.653293056
    74.397865216
    77.074788864
    73.011555840]
>> [p,h] = signrank(language1,language2)
    p = 0.0625
    h = 0
```

Comparison 2:

```
>> language3= 
        [82.83918413
        84.30715213
        82.91308314
        82.87125197
        83.17255706] 
>> language2= [66.954494208
        71.653293056
        74.397865216
        77.074788864
        73.011555840]
>> [p,h] = signrank(language3,language2)
        p = 0.0625
        h = 0
```

I did not utilised a Kruskal-Wallis test to compare the three at the same time because I need the comparisons separated. Thanks a lot, any help and comment is highly appreciated.

Comment: I found the answer few minutes later by keeping on searching. I leave the question and answer that helped me, in case someone else would find it useful.

Comment: Isn't it interesting that $0.0625 = (1/2)^{5-1}$ :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the usual rank based tests have a discrete distribution based on counting of arrangements.

So the possible p-values will be multiples of some smallest increment (typically the reciprocal of the total number of counts - or sometimes multiples of some multiple of that).

This also means that there's a smallest possible p-value, when the test statistic is as extreme as it can be.

The data from your three samples don't overlap at all:

[image: stripchart of three nonoverlapping samples]

so you're in this situation. The signed rank test statistic can't be any more extreme and so attains its lowest possible p-value.

However you should NOT use the Kruskal Wallis and the signed rank test on the same data. The signed rank test is for *paired* samples and the Kruskal Wallis for independent samples.

The two sample test for independent samples (i.e. the one that corresponds to the Kruskal-Wallis) is the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney.

Alternatively, if your samples are dependent, you should replace the Kruskal-Wallis with something else (possibly the Friedman test, though there are other tests).

Answer (score 8):

[Wilcoxon signed-rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) just takes in account the signs of the differences of values of every pair of data, and it doesn't take in account how large is such a difference. Therefore, the only thing that matters in your data is that all values in one group are larger than the matching values in the other group. That is, the only thing a Wilcoxon text will see in your data is a set of 5 pairs of positive signs: {+1,+1,+1,+1,+1}. Then, you are getting the same result for both tests because (from Wilcoxon point of view) both use exactly the same data.

**End note after Glen_b's answer**

If you had used [Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) - that suits better your problem as Glen_b noticed - you would also have got the same p-value for both comparisons, because it only takes in account relative positions, just like Wilcoxon test.

Answer (score -1):

I have just found that "[if you have five or fewer values, the Wilcoxon test will always give a P value greater than 0.05, no matter how far the sample median is from the hypothetical median](http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/6/statistics/index.htm?stat_interpreting_results_wilcoxon_.htm)", that explains why the p-value is the same. I tried with more than five data points and the results are different, with H0 rejected.

Answer is, the values are like that because that is what happens when using Wilcoxon with 5 or less data points.

Comment: I'd be wary of a site that says this: "The nonparametric Wilcoxon signed rank test compares the median of a single column of numbers against a hypothetical median. Don't confuse it with the Wilcoxon matched pairs test which compares two paired or matched groups." without a hint of irony. The "matched pairs" test applies the signed ranks test to the pair-differences and compares to a hypothesized median of zero. They're *exactly* the same test. To warn you that way without any explanation of that basic fact is to effectively mislead you about what's going on.