# Is there a non-parametric equivalent of the t-test for a small sample size?

Tags: nonparametric, z-test

I have weather stations collecting data (temperature, humidity, solar radiation, wind, etc.) inside and outside low-tech greenhouses. Four of the weather stations are inside, and one is outside. I am testing to see if the differences between the weather station data inside and outside is statistically different from zero.

Because I have an unequal number of replicates inside and outside the greenhouses, I calculated the difference for each variable between each weather station inside each greenhouse and the one weather station outside. This gives me a sample size of 4. Sometimes 3 because I lost a replicate for part of the study. I was hoping to test the significance of the differences from zero rather than the original weather station data.

I am looking for a statistical test that works on small sample sizes and non-normal distributed data. I am thinking a non-parametric alternative to the z-test.

I tried the wilcoxon sign test, but I am getting no statistical significance where there should be some. For example, testing if 3 values in the -300 range are statistically different from 0. The test said no.

Please let me know if I provided enough information about my study.

Comment: Even if you had normality, you your test would be wrong in any case! You can't treat each of those differences as independent, because they're all differences from the *same* outside value.

Comment: @Glen_b Good point. Would it be better to test the 3 inside versus the one outside or is there a test that doesn't assume independence and works for small samples?

Comment: I think the best answer would be none of the above. It might be best to post a question that asks about how to test in a situation like that (assuming its possible at all), rather than you trying to guess ways to do it and asking about problems that arise with your solutions. You may need to clarify some details about your situation if you post.

Comment: @Glen_b Okay. I posted a new question. Please let me know what further details are needed. [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287189/what-is-the-appropriate-test-for-a-small-sample-size)

Answer (score 1):

In first place, the difference between t-test and z-test is that for z-test population variance is known. If you are looking for an equivalent non parametric test, variance doesn't matter and therefore "equivalent to z-test" is equal to "equivalent  to t-test".

In general, non parametric tests don't use actual value of data. They just use ranks. Therefore, you will get the same p-value with quite similar samples (like {1} and {1.1,1.3,1.5}) than with very different samples (like {1} and {1000, 1001, 1002}) because the only information the Wilcox test uses is that the three values in the second sample are larger than the only one in the first one. Furthermore, since even this extreme result is likely to happen if the null hypothesis is true, p-values will always be large in your setting (you can see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232927/same-p-value-is-it-normal/232932#232932) to a similar question).

In any case, if you are taking series of measures (for example, daily), I wouldn't compare data from a single day. I would take in account all days in the same test. Performing a two way unbalanced ANOVA with inside/outside as first factor and day as second factor (or block) may tell you if there is a significant difference between inside and outside. You can check for normality of residuals after the test, but they are likely to be normal enough to keep ANOVA conclusions valid.

Comment: I would prefer to use the differences I calculated. Solar radiation and wind speed are not normally distributed, so I do need a non-parametric solution.

Comment: If you use data from several days, means and statistics will be approximately normally distributed, even if temperatures aren't.

Comment: Wouldn't you run in to correlation issues because what the temperature was at the last interval influences the next temperature?

Comment: That's the reason I suggest a two way anova instead of just taking all inside mesures as a single sample and outside measures as another single sample. Measures from the same day aren't independent - at least, I wouldn't expect them to be. However, I would guess that it doesn't matter if the sample is large enough.

Comment: "p-values will always be large" is true relative to parametric tests only when the distributional assumptions of the parametric tests are true. Non-parametric tests may give much smaller p-values than a corresponding parametric test if these assumtions are violated. For example, Spearman's correlation coefficient (non-parametric) may give a smaller p-value than Pearsons if the functional relationship between the two variables is monotonic, and quite curved.

Comment: @Alexis P-values are going to be large when comparing a two samples of sizes 1 and 3, no matter which values the variables take. Of course, for other problems non parametric test give small p-values and are sometimes better than their parametric equivalent, but the answer is discussing outcomes of the OP's problem.

Comment: My comment specifically noted "*relative to*". :)